# Saving variables on server in php

Tags: php, memcached

Is there a way, in php, to save a variable on server so it stay there for all of the requests (not session, need to be saved for all users ever)?
i'm new in php, in asp.net is use the 'application' context.

thanks.

Comment: Certain user requests or all requests?

Comment: go for database then. your fears are just nonsense. database IS meant to store application data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP does not have an *application context*, probably because of it's script nature. You may store data for an user and for a limited period if time in the session, but if you want something per application you should implement it yourself. Storing in a database would be best. By using a class that implements [ArrayAccess](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) you will replicate an application context.

If you want some sort of fast access to you data you could use [Memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php). But that is not really application data. It's just caching. That means you have to have a fallback to something (database) if the data you want is no longer found in the cache.

So if you want a fast and reliable way to store application data in PHP you should do it with a database table for storing it and Memcache for fast access.

Comment: going to the database will be terrible... there is no way to implement it on the server memory?

Comment: Why do you say that? You need to store (application) data. That's what databases are for. I would have suggested file system too, but I think that you should store in a table in the database because it's safer.

Comment: lets say i have a very complex query that takes time to execute. the query result would not change in the near hour for sure. how can i avoid keep executing the query every minute?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you still need the permanent storage location. Memcache may last a very long time, but it's still a cache and does not offer any guarantee that you will find you data in it.

Comment: @Nir make this query run fast.

Comment: Even a very fast query usually won't match taking the result from memory. i wont trust 'memcache' blindly if it return nothing then i'm going to the db... but if it's there i'm good.

Comment: Seems you're all sorted out. Have fun coding it!

Comment: @Nir millions sites does keep their data in the database and quite happy with it. I doubt your site is something special.

Comment: You misunderstood me. i don't say the database is a waste - i say that i want to avoid visiting him unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Answer (score -2):

look at `$_SESSION` variable ;-)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: On answers that date from 2010, really !?